# Postion: absolute;

Tags: html, css

/*codepen link used to be here*/

When I don't give my main-footer a position, the paragraph element isn't relative to the Root Element. Why is it relative to my .banner element? It is not it's ancestor. Is this a bug?

```
.main-footer {
 /*position: relative;
}*/

.main-footer p {
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 1px;
}
```

> "Elements that are relatively positioned remain in the normal
>   flow of the document. In contrast, an element that is absolutely
>   positioned is taken out of the flow; thus, other elements are
>   positioned as if it did not exist. The absolutely positioned element
>   is positioned relative to its nearest positioned ancestor (i.e., the
>   nearest ancestor that is not static). If a positioned ancestor doesn't
>   exist, it is positioned relative to the ICB (initial containing
>   block), which the containing block of the document's root element." -
>   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position

Comment: Please try to come up with a more meaningful header/title/question. Also please include all relevant code *in the question itself*, that includes HTML. Don't make us go off site to find important context.

Comment: ok i will do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your codepen, after removing the positioning on `.main-footer`, the `.main-footer p` is relative to the `body` which is the closest root ancestor. It maybe looks like it's relative to the `.banner` because they end about the same place, but if you entirely remove the extra elements you can see it pretty clearly.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WPOjOZ

Testing in Chrome